# Too much recursion error on firefox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, recursion

I'm getting too much recursion error at the following piece of code, when I'm running the application on Firefox. The code is expected to create a graphical tree structure in the browser. The method take a Json as an input, traverses through the keys and checks if the value corresponding to the key is "Leaf". If the value is "Leaf", it displays it on the browser and moves on to the next key, else it traverses recursively through the child nodes till the "Leaf" is reached. The node with all its children are displayed on the browser:

```
function createmasterJson(data) {
    var json = '';
    for (var index in data) {
        var child = data[index];
        if (child == 'Leaf') {
            json = json + createLeafNode(index);
        } else {
            if (child.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
                    json = json + createNonLeafNode(index, createmasterJson(child[i]));
                }
            } else {
                json = json + createLeafNode(index);
            }
        }
    }
    return json;
}

function createLeafNode(index){
    return '{ "attributes": { "id" :"' + index + '_' + Math.random() +'"}, "data": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '+ index +'" },';
}

function createNonLeafNode(index, child){
    return '{ "attributes": { "id" :"' + index + '_' + Math.random() +'"}, "data": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '+ index +'" ,"state": "closed", "children" : ['+child.substring(0, child.length - 1)+']},';
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke that function?

Comment: `createLeafNode`? `createNonLeafNode`? `data`?
We can't help you debug your code if we don't know what's going on. Please add the 2 functions I mentioned to your question, as well as what data is passed to the function.

Comment: If `data` contains a string value other then `Leaf` then that's what you get since you recursively call `createmasteJSON()` with the same one character string. You definitely need some different condition then `if (child.length)`. If you want a condition for array then try `if (Object.prototype.toString.call(child) == '[object Array]')`.

Comment: Fire up your browser's developer tools, set a breakpoint and step through your code. That's what most of us would need to do (mentally or actually) so it's not too much asked if you try that yourself first.

Comment: You should probably be using `JSON.stringify` instead of making an object string.